# How to enable all node.js harmony "in progress" features?

Tags: node.js

```
node --v8-options | grep harmony
  --es_staging (enable all completed harmony features)
  --harmony (enable all completed harmony features)
  --harmony_shipping (enable all shipped harmony fetaures)
  --harmony_modules (enable "harmony modules" (in progress))
  --harmony_regexps (enable "harmony regular expression extensions" (in progress))
  --harmony_proxies (enable "harmony proxies" (in progress))
  --harmony_sloppy_function (enable "harmony sloppy function block scoping" (in progress))
  --harmony_sloppy_let (enable "harmony let in sloppy mode" (in progress))
  --harmony_unicode_regexps (enable "harmony unicode regexps" (in progress))
  --harmony_reflect (enable "harmony Reflect API" (in progress))
  --harmony_destructuring (enable "harmony destructuring" (in progress))
  --harmony_default_parameters (enable "harmony default parameters" (in progress))
  --harmony_sharedarraybuffer (enable "harmony sharedarraybuffer" (in progress))
  --harmony_atomics (enable "harmony atomics" (in progress))
  --harmony_simd (enable "harmony simd" (in progress))
  --harmony_array_includes (enable "harmony Array.prototype.includes")
  --harmony_tostring (enable "harmony toString")
  --harmony_concat_spreadable (enable "harmony isConcatSpreadable")
  --harmony_rest_parameters (enable "harmony rest parameters")
  --harmony_sloppy (enable "harmony features in sloppy mode")
  --harmony_arrow_functions (enable "harmony arrow functions")
  --harmony_new_target (enable "harmony new.target")
  --harmony_object_observe (enable "harmony Object.observe")
  --harmony_spreadcalls (enable "harmony spread-calls")
  --harmony_spread_arrays (enable "harmony spread in array literals")
  --harmony_object (enable "harmony Object methods")
```

[node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) comes with a lot of features that are disabled by default (either because they are still in development or are in staging). The `--harmony` flag enables all completed features.

How to enable all "in progress" features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at what flags are currently "in progress" with

```
node --v8-options | grep "in progress"
```

The output as of this post looks like

```
--harmony_modules (enable "harmony modules" (in progress))
--harmony_array_includes (enable "harmony Array.prototype.includes" (in progress))
// ...
// (I've removed the other lines, which look like the above)
```

So you could easily parse it to suit your needs.

On the subject: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/#which-features-are-in-progress

Comment: Clearly I know which features are in progress, as I have pasted the entire list of available `--harmony` features. The question is if there is a simple way to run `node` using all "in progress" features. It appears there isn't. I would need to write a bash script (e.g. `node --v8-options | grep harmony | awk '/harmony/ && $1 ~ /^--/{print $1}'`) to parse them and then run `node` program with those flags.

Comment: I imagined you knew it, the thing about not having the list is that you don't have to care about it being up to date, you just write the script and you're done :)

Comment: For other's reference, to run `node` program with all the present `--harmony` options, the full command would be `node $(node --v8-options | awk '/harmony/ && $1 ~ /^--/{print $1}') ./your-script`

Comment: `--harmony_modules` is a "bad option" as of Node v7.4.0

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly use the "**in progress**" flag as you use Harmony flag. for Features "in progress" use the "--harmony" flag itself.
If you want to know the features in progress run

> node --v8-options | grep "in progress"

Most flags when you use the command

> node --v8-options | grep harmony

are "**in progress**", Unless they are enabled by default. to verify the shipped ones would be to run

> node --v8-options | grep -A1 harmony

If the default shows true, then it should work properly